# Less.js + IE8 = Object doesn't support property or method 'bind'

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, less, bind, ie8-browser-mode

Whilst doing some cross-browser testing (using IE Edge in IE8 mode), the page fails to render correctly due to an error with Less JS (v2.7.1). The console log is:

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'bind'
File: less.js, Line: 1896, Column: 1

Same goes for the minified version
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'bind'
File: less.min.js, Line: 13, Column: 27226

I've read that IE8 and below do not support bind hence the problem.

Can anyone offer a solution on how I can get around this issue without having to dump Less JS completely (not an option)?

Comment: See http://lesscss.org/usage/#browser-support, i.e.: "If you need to run less in an older browser, please use an [es-5 shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) which will add the javascript features that less requires."

Comment: Thanks. Will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a polyfill for `bind`, like the [MDN's one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Polyfill). There are some differences with the native one, as noted in the link.

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
    Function.prototype.bind = function(oThis) {
       if (typeof this !== 'function') {
       // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5
       // internal IsCallable function
       throw new TypeError('Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable');
    }

    var aArgs   = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
        fToBind = this,
        fNOP    = function() {},
        fBound  = function() {
            return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP
                   ? this
                   : oThis,
                   aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
        };

    if (this.prototype) {
        // Function.prototype doesn't have a prototype property
        fNOP.prototype = this.prototype; 
    }
    fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

    return fBound;
};
```

}

Comment: Is this a matter of simply adding this to the less.js file? I'm pretty basic when it comes to JS so not sure if this is a simple copy>paste fix or if it needs to be integrated.

Comment: It must be executed before the code which uses bind. A separate script  loaded before less.js will work. Perhaps you will need other pollyfills for features not supported by IE8.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance Vincente. It did indeed bypass the error, but now to only show another (SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'keys' - File: less.min.js, Line: 10, Column: 28054). I think I'll start looking for an alternative solution.